# WebService VB passando parâmetros para C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Bom dia,

Temos dois sistemas, um deles é em VB e o outro em C# um gestor de identidades (que serve para unificar o login, vamos colocar mais sistemas dentro dele para que exista apenas um usuário de login), temos que passar o Usuário e o ID da aplicação para o sistema em C#. esse sistema vai verificar se o usuário existe, se existir permite fazer login, e o sistema em VB deve estourar uma mensagem na tela dizendo que o usuário existe, estamos usando WEB.Api.

Desde já, grato.

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Desculpe haha,
Como devo passar via WebService tais parâmetros? não entendo muito sobre webservices, lembrando que o em C# está a usar WEB.Api, ou seja, acredito que posso pegar os parâmetros com Get...